# What is the kernel used by `statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_density.KDEMultivariate`

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

I notice that there's no `kernel` option in `statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_density.KDEMultivariate`. I'm wondering what is the kernel used by it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer. In the source code of `statsmodels`, the implementation of `pdf`, i.e. [this](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/960f0d3ed9a7b4cf698137e28ae05f6aefeec7f4/statsmodels/nonparametric/kernel_density.py#L162), uses the function, `gpke`, i.e. [this](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/960f0d3ed9a7b4cf698137e28ae05f6aefeec7f4/statsmodels/nonparametric/_kernel_base.py#L456). 

 Now, even if the method, `gpke` provides the option of supplying kernel type by the argument, `ckertype`, but it's default to `gaussian`. And back to the caller of `pdf`, the `ckertype` argument is not specified explicitly and hence it's set to the default value of `Gaussian`...

 BTW, I found the `statsmodels`, albeit being very comprehensive and rigorous, is awfully implemented in python. Guess I'll implement the whole thing in c++ instead...

Comment: MultivariateKDE uses a slow python loop. Nobody converted it to cython yet. Univariate kde has fft option which is fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just implemented part of it in c++ instead

Answer (score 0):

The website https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/nonparametric.html states that 
"Multivariate estimation (as provided by KDEMultivariate) uses product kernels."

Is that answer your quesion?

Comment: Thanks for you repsonse. I just found the answer... It uses "Gaussian". Guess I can use the `gpke` method instead. But I think statsmodels is just too slow. I'll move to c++ instead... Thanks anyway